# How to enable vscode-server's automatic update logs?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I'm stucked with the Remote-SSH extension which needs to be updated according to my client version.

The automatic VSCode server update is starting but stay locked into the following state:

[image: Vscode terminal info]

I suspect a network problem (proxy, cacert, ...), so I need to get logs from the process which peform the download (I don't know if it is client or server side).

How can I get more verbosity from VSCode update service?